# Dropdown option not getting selected using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to select a dropdown option in the form using Selenium webdriver in Python. The XPATH is correct, I also verified it is going to the right dropdown option but in the end it is not selecting it.

I have tried similar code for another website that has a dropdown. But it's not working for this particular website.

Can someone please help out with this?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.cersai.org.in/CERSAI/dbtrsrch.prg")

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='borrowerType']")
all_options = elem.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")

for option in all_options:
    if option.get_attribute("value") == "IND":
        option.click()
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange that Select class did not work. It needs a JavaScript call.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.cersai.org.in/CERSAI/dbtrsrch.prg")
driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('borrowerType').selectedIndex = '2'")
```

Comment: wow, this works. thanks a ton.
there's one more challenge though. If you notice, when trying manually, if we select any of the dropdown from "type of debtor", it adds new set of fields in the form. However, when we are automating the dropdown selection, it does not add any new fields

Comment: @Giffen : I did look into, but got 


CERSAI
Central Registry of Securitisation Asset Reconstruction and Security Interest of India
The CERSAI site is under maintenance.

The site will not be available from 23-Aug-2021 09:00 PM till 24-Aug-2021 12:00 AM .

Answer (score 1):

You should add a wait before accessing the dropdown element to make it loaded.
Also, this is a `Select` element, you can treat it in a special way as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://www.cersai.org.in/CERSAI/dbtrsrch.prg")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='borrowerType']")))

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='borrowerType']"))
# select by visible text
select.select_by_value('IND')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually tried to add a 10 second time wait but it is still not working. Dropdown values are getting loaded as soon as the page is loaded. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Are you sure you added the wait in correct way? Have you tried to use this code, what I wrote here?

Comment: [link](https://notepad.pw/96vwt2u2) - tried this code. It doesn't work. Do you think there's anything wrong with it?

Comment: I tried the solution provided by you but it's still not working

Comment: @Prophet : it's strange, I did try with explicit wait and action chains, nothing happened. there's no iframe either.

Comment: Thanks! I see no logical cause while this will not work...

Comment: also I notice one thing, with automation the second drop down is getting highlighted but no element got selected whereas with manual run there's no highlight on both the drop down. Anyway upvoted for your efforts. I will continue to look into this for sometime now.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, @cruisepandey.
I have tried similar code in another web form and it works there. It's strange why it's not working here

Comment: @Giffen : try out the below solution, should work for you. It needed a JS call.

Comment: @Prophet : It needed a JS call, But still I would wander, why select did not work. I think you cannot just rely on Select.